# How do I configure the Google Cloud Platform Ingress to serve a static page if the backend health check fails?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a website running on GCP Kubernetes. It uses an Ingress to receive traffic initially and is then passed down to a Deployment/Workload.

If for some reason the backend health check fails, we receive a generic 500 status page. I would like to serve a more stylish version of that page for consumers. Ideally we'd tune the system so this won't happen, but sometimes it still occurs.

[image: Default Server Error Page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such feature exists as of now in the GCLB to do that. You can always use your own ingress controller [like Nginx](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) and set-up the following configuration:

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
        location = /custom_50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Our Rep from GCP responded similarly. They recommended turning on Cloud CDN to reduce the likelihood of 500 during rolling updates...

Comment: You can ask the rep to put this as a feature request.

Comment: will do. Do you know if it's possible with other K8s services (AWS, Azure, etc?)